# Setting color as primary for a mat-radio-group in CSS

Tags: angular, angular-material

The following sets the color of the mat-radio-group to primary.

```
    <mat-radio-group color="primary">
```

However, I could not find a method to take the 'color=primary' part to CSS. The following code in CSS does not give the desired result. How should I be doing this?

```
    mat-radio-group {
      color: primary;
      }
```

Comment: The material components already take the colors from your theme. So you just to override your theme colors. And it will effect all your components. You don't have to do it in each component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// You can provide Custom Theming for Angular Material
// import angular material
@import "~@angular/material/theming";

// Include the common styles for Angular Material. We include this here so that you only
// have to load a single css file for Angular Material in your app.
// Be sure that you only ever include this mixin once!
@include mat-core();

// Define the palettes for your theme using the Material Design palettes available in palette.scss
// Available color palettes: https://material.io/design/color/
$app-ui-primary: mat-palette($mat-indigo);  // you can change mat-colors based on requirement
$app-ui-accent: mat-palette($mat-pink, A200, A100, A400);

// The warn palette is optional (defaults to red).
$app-ui-warn: mat-palette($mat-red);

// Create the theme object (a Sass map containing all of the palettes).
$app-ui-theme: mat-light-theme(
  $app-ui-primary,
  $app-ui-accent,
  $app-ui-warn
);

// Include theme styles for core and each component used in your app.
// Alternatively, you can import and @include the theme mixins for each component
// that you are using.
@include angular-material-theme($app-ui-theme);
```

Add this to your styles.scss and change the `$app-ui-primary` to other color like `$mat-pink` or other material palette color. That will change the color for `color="primary"` defined tags